# How to fetch data from server for a nested route ember 2.3.0

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js

I have a post model and a comments model that are related as shown below:

```
//  app/models/post.js

import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
 //....
 comments: DS.hasMany('comment'),
 //....
})

// app/models/comment.js

import DS from 'ember-data'

export default DS.Model.extend({
 //....
 ad: DS.belongsTo('post'),,
 //....
})
```

In `app/router.js` I have

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('post', {path: '/post/:post_id'}, function() {
    this.route('comments');
  });
)};
```

I have a `post` template in `app/templates/post.hbs` that looks like this:

```
<h2>{{model.title}}</h2>
<p>{{model.body}}</p>

  {{#link-to "post.comments"}}
    <h2>Comments</h2>
  {{/link-to}}
  {{outlet}}
```

I also have a template to render the comments in `app/templates/post/comments.hbs`

```
{#each model as |comment|}}
  <p>{{comment.body}}</p>
{{/each}}
{{outlet}}
```

I want when someone clicks on the comments link on the post template, the comments template be rendered on the `{{outlet}}` of the post template. The problem I have is fetching the data for `comments` model. I have a route for the `comments` in `app/routes/post/comments.js` and it looks like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(){
    //I don't know what to do here.
  }
});
```

The comments in my backend server are exposed on `/posts/:post_id/comments` endpoint. How can i do to get the comments on the comments template?

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have the `Post` loaded in the parent `route:post`, your `route:post.comments` can simply ask for the `Comment`s from it:

```
// app/routes/post/comments.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(){
    const post = this.modelFor('post');
    return post.get('comments');
  }
});
```

Comment: when i do this I get an error: `GET http://localhost:4200/comments/6 404 (Not Found)` `GET http://localhost:4200/comments/2 404 (Not Found)`  `Error while processing route: post.comments Adapter operation failed Error: Adapter operation failed`

Comment: Is it possible that the API for a post's comments returns _partial_ data and that in the template you're rendering you're relying on a field that didn't come back in the initial GET?

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to make this work. With the help of James answer, The only thing that I had to do was to set a dynamic namespace for the `CommentAdapter`. 
I generated a `comment` adapter using the ember generator and changed my `app/routes/post/comments.js` file to look like this:

```
// app/routes/post/comments.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(){
      const post = this.modelFor('post');
      this.store.adapterFor('comment').set('namespace', `posts/${post.id}`);
      return this.store.query('comment', post.id);
    }
 });
```

This works as expected.